# How to get reminder in excel after each hour

Tags: excel

I used this formula: `=if(Now()==Time(11:00:00),"Time up for B6","Error")` but it seems some issue. how should i get reminder for each hour in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. Try this variant:

```
=IF(NOW()=TIME(11,0,0),"Time up for B6","Error")
```

You'll get reminder on each 11:00:00. IF you need reminder on every hour, then you can use this formula:

```
=IF(MINUTE(NOW())=0,"Time up for B6","Error")
```

**Update:**
If you want to update cells without F9 key pressing, then you need to use VBA macro. VBA can force cell re-calculate every 1 minute:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "UpdateClock")
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateClock()
    Call Sheet1.Range("A1").Calculate
    Call Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "UpdateClock")
End Sub
```

UpdateClock procedure must be in Module (not in Sheet or Workbook)

Comment: ummm.. just tried this. but showing "error" only. i tried to set time to 10:59 in system clock and wait for min. but status not changed.

Comment: @RedSwan The cell won't change by itself, since it will not be evauated again unless you press 'F9' for recalculate.

Comment: @RedSwan I updated my post. With VBA macro works fine for me.